# Script error after a couple of tests

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

when i have 190 tests jenkins can run anything fine, after 191 I get the following error :

> Chrome 64.0.3282 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR { "message": "Script error.\nat
>   :0:0", "str": "Script error.\nat :0:0" }

**Can someone tell me what does this mean?**

---

Karma version (output of karma --version): 2.0.0

Relevant part of your karma.config.js file

````
module.exports = function (config)
{
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli'],
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
```
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome_no_sandbox', 'Chrome'], customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_no_sandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'] // for running within Docker
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    colors: true
  });
};`
````

Answer (score 12):

Run Karma with `--single-run=false` option, which is default one, e.g.

`karma start --single-run=false  --config=test/unit/karma.conf.js`

Then, open `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` and open Console. You will see actual issue there.

[image]